# A flat question [bass guitar]

Tags: bass-guitar

What note is the note under FNG: 4?  It’s A flat, how do you play A flat on the A string?
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the 4 above the note is a fingering?  Then you'd play it on the 4th fret of the E string.

Comment: @ggcg yes it’s fingering.

Comment: Then I think you have the answer.   You play it on the E string

Comment: @ggcg Actually, it’s the 3rd fret (4th finger), an A flat on the A string.  So do you just move down that fret to the E?

Comment: Im confused by your question but there is an answer that echos my comments

Comment: I changed the tag to *bass guitar*. Am I correct, or is this some weird way to write for ordinary guitar?  P.S. I understand that normal guitar is pitched an octave lower than written, however I have never seen it scored in the bass clef.

Comment: I'm curious: why did you think that the A string was specified?

Comment: @db. FYI, the suggested fingerings here are suggested for upright Bass. e.g. the C# is 4th finger and B is 1st; yet this is only 2 frets away. It's a valid and good way to play E Bass, but this posting could be for [Bass] :)

Comment: @paiego - OP mentions **frets** so it's more likely to be EB.

Comment: @Tim It is electric bass, and the book is also for the EB.

Comment: @Tim. Yes, no doubt it's EB (as dlb verified). Yet the original question doesn't mention *frets* and could just as easily be understood and answered by an upright player.

Comment: @paiego - I agree. Finger numbers on(any)  bass do not relect fret numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply, you don't. You can't. That A string is note A open, and you can't go to a lower note using that string. The fingering says 4, which is a good clue to playing the bottom string (E), with 4th finger, on 4th fret. That takes you down a semitone from A, to A♭. Job done!